# Modifying increment value in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was playing around with Python 2.7 and wanted to know if there was a clean way to code a Python equivalent of this Java loop (where you can modify the increment value in the loop):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 64; i *= 2) {
    # i = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64
}
```

It seems like in Python you can use `range()`, but you can only get every nth element (e.g. `for i in range(1, 65, 2)` will get you every odd element).

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but you may find dicussion on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645240/multiple-loop-control-variables-in-python-for-loop) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java for loops are different from Python's. You an use a `while` loop for the same effect.

```
i = 1
while (i<=64):
    print(i)
    i*=2
```

Else you can implement your own range function using a custom generator

```
>>> def my_own_range(n):
...     i = 1
...     while(i<=n):
...         yield(i)
...         i*=2
... 
>>> for i in my_own_range(64):
...     print(i)
... 
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
```